# Rails. Splitting a radio button collection into columns with Form Helpers or Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, radio-group, form-helpers

I've the following form that uses Simple_form gem:

```
<%= simple_form_for @match_prediction do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :outcome, label: false, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['local', match.local_team], ['Tie', 'Tie'], ['visit', match.visiting_team]], label_method: :second, value_method: :first %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Currently it works as expected, meaning: Renders 3 radio buttons, exclusive from each other and each resulting in a unique string being passed to the server.

**The problem**: I'd like to separate each of the radio buttons across different columns in a Bootstrap grid like below:

```
<div class="row prediction">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <!-- FIRST RADIO BUTTON HERE -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <!-- SECOND RADIO BUTTON HERE -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <!-- THIRD RADIO BUTTON HERE -->
  </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
</div>
```

Since the whole collection is specified in one line within the form code, I can't simply split lines and insert them in the relevant HTML.

Is there a way to achieve this either via simple_form or vanilla rails form helpers?

I've considered splitting the radios as separate form inputs but this would allow to select more that one option at once. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the generated html output for `<%= f.input :outcome, ... %>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coudn't you use a standard rails helper in simple_form form? What about using the `radio_button` helper directly. [Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button)

```
<div class="row prediction">
  <div class="col-sm-4">   
    <%= radio_button 'match_prediction', 'outcome', 'local', checked: @match_prediction.outcome == 'local' %> <%= match.local_team %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <%= radio_button 'match_prediction', 'outcome', 'Tie', checked: @match_prediction.outcome == 'Tie' %> <%= 'Tie' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">      
    <%= radio_button 'match_prediction', 'outcome', 'visit', checked: @match_prediction.outcome == 'visit' %> <%= match.visiting_team %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
</div>
```

And if it is possible to access standard FormHelper in simple_form you can call:

```
<%= f.radio_button 'outcome', 'xzy' %> <%= 'whatever' %>
```

Comment: Simon, thanks a lot this works. I definitely have to re-read the docs to get a better grasp of this. Thanks!

Comment: I also used simple_form in the beginning, but later switched for all projects, because if you want to change something there you have to implement your custom tag helper the 'simple_form'-way and that was pretty hard.

Comment: Indeed I'm starting to see the limitations of Simple Form, I'll take your advice for sure. Cheers!

Comment: I can enjoy a Sunday reading this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html :)